# WPAllImport - Mutliple Suppliers - Same Products

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, woocommerce, wpallimport

I am trying to do an import with WPALLIMPORT (Wordpress, Woocommerce).
Problem I am having:

I have multiple suppliers, some of them have a few products that are the same, I would like to choose the cheapest "duplicate product" to import, they have different XML structures, but I am running the Manufacturer SKU as the Unique Identifier so I should be able to pick the duplicates up.

I am just unsure how I will only import the cheapest price into the system? Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could achieve this by some custom coding. Find the current product price compare it to the manufacturer price, if its lower then use the manufacturer price otherwise keep the current price.